# Service invoked too many times for one day jdbc connection, for only one user

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

I've written a Google Apps Script app that is running in embedded windows on a Google Site. Our board uses this system to assist in virtual meetings. They can do stuff like voting, speaker queueing, and attendance. The script runs as the user accessing the page.
It's been working well for a few years, but we've been having issues with one specific user, and not sure why.
The script hooks into Google Cloud SQL in the background to store all its info connect using JDBC.
For one user, who happens to be the board chair, he often gets "Exception: Service invoked too many times for one day: jdbc connection" when he tries to access the system.
The limits for JDBC look like 10,000 or 50,000 depending on Google account type (we're on Google Workspace for non-profits, but the user isn't on our domain).
I can't imagine he's actually using 10,000+ connections in the span of a few hours. No one else has ever reported this issue.
The line of code where it fails is my SQL Connection command:

```
conn = Jdbc.getConnection(myString, DBUser, DBPassword)
```

There are 60+ other users accessing the same system, with no issues. We also have sometimes expanded it to around 250 users and still never had anyone else report the issue.
I see the errors in SQL log viewer as well.

```
{
  "insertId": "-***************",
  "jsonPayload": {
    "serviceContext": {
      "service": "************"
    },
    "context": {
      "reportLocation": {
        "functionName": "getSQL",
        "filePath": "Code-SQLCommands",
        "lineNumber": 110
      }
    },
    "message": "Exception: Service invoked too many times for one day: jdbc connection.\n    at getSQL(Code-SQLCommands:110:19)\n    at isUserGroupMember(Code-SQLCommands:1089:14)\n    at checkIfAdmin(Code-General:258:13)\n    at doGet(Code-General:93:19)"
  },
  "resource": {
    "type": "app_script_function",
    "labels": {
      "project_id": ***********
      "invocation_type": "web app",
      "function_name": "doGet"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2021-05-06T16:15:26.154Z",
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "labels": {
    "script.googleapis.com/process_id": "E***********************",
    "script.googleapis.com/user_key": "A****************************",
    "script.googleapis.com/deployment_id": "A*************************",
    "script.googleapis.com/project_key": "M**********************"
  },
  "logName": "projects/***************/logs/script.googleapis.com%2Fconsole_logs",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2021-05-06T16:15:26.910147206Z"
}
```

Any thoughts on where to begin looking? I've tried looking through the code to see if I can find any places where some loop is causing thousands of connections to JDBC, but haven't found anything, and also don't know why others wouldn't be affected if that was the issue.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is this user doing repetitive but small queries that return fast?  The reason I'm asking is that they don't measure the quota on total numbers but they look for users that are exceeding the rate.  Where the rate is calculated like quota for the day/total seconds for a day.

Comment: MetaMan, that is possible. He monitors the speaker queue. By default, it checks every 3 seconds for users who've requested to speak. However two other people are monitoring it as well, with no errors reported.

Comment: Try going to every 10 seconds.

Comment: Could a user with poor internet, like lots of packet loss, cause way more connection attempts as there are retry packets sent frequently?  We've been running pingplotter on his machine, and noticed he's on ipv6, which I don't think should matter, and some of the hops between him and Google.ca have lots of packet loss, though no packet loss to google.ca itself (don't know what IP he actually is hitting for apps script, so just used generic Google IP). Latency is fine at 40ms.

Comment: I would think that would have just the opposite effect.